# Multiple page files in one layout

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Now I'm in https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts page

What I want to ask is, how to implement multiple page files in one layout? Because `children` default call page.js file

After show list of games, it will show game page, but before open game page there is instruction page

`layout.js`, `page.js` (main game page), `instruction.js` (instuction page)

Refer to link above, how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have multiple pages in one layout in Next.js. The layout gets loaded by the page. Each page only loads a single layout.

You might want your layout to hold a navigation bar with links to instructions and main game page.

Layout example:

```
<div id="left-sidebar">
  {/* these are links to the pages */}
  <Link href="game-page" />
  <Link href="instructions-page" />
</div>
<div id="main-panel">
  {/* this is element in which each page will show up */}
  {children}
</div>
```

Comment: instruction page is like loading page, but there are instructions regarding the game to be played and there is a button to skip or continue to the game page

Comment: or should I move the instruction.page file to component folder?

Comment: If instructions need to be displayed at the same time as the game, then instructions and game should be components and should be placed on the same page